# Error when running minikube tutorial export POD_NAME

Tags: get, kubectl, minikube

I'm running the kubernets bootcamp tutorial using minikube and one of the tutorial asks to register the POD_NAME by running a command:

```
export POD_NAME="$(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}')"
```

When I attempt to run it, I get the following error:

```
error: error parsing template {{range .items}}{{.metadata.name}}{{\n}}{{end}}, template: output:1: unexpected "\\" in command
export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ export POD_NAME="$(kubectl get pods -o go-template --template '{{rang ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I am running minikube in Windows OS and using Docker Desktop for docker container driver.

I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't run the export command in Windows cmd as the cmd doesn't have the terminal paths stored in it
If you are using wsl in your Windows using its terminal to access the cluster and export the pod
If you are using Windows for the K8s cluster main endpoint you can use
`windows powershell`  and that should work without any issues